# Magento: the xml block is doubled

Tags: xml, magento, block

cms.xml has default value:

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
         </block>
     </reference>
</default>
```

My local.xml has follow content:

```
<default>
     <reference name="footer">
             <remove name="store_switcher" />
             <remove name="footer_links" />

             <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.links.wrapper" translate="label" before="-">
                <label>Footer Links Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottomLinks</value></action>

                <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
                </block>
             </block>

      </reference>
</default>
```

But in this case I get doubled footer_links block. The first one is as it is in a page static block, the other one is wrapped into div.bottomLinks.

How to fix this? How to show only one wrapped block without cms.xml editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in local xml

```
<default>
....
</default>

<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="cms_footer_links" />
    </reference name>
</cms_index_index>
```

And in

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links">
```

You should change name to something like "cms_footer_another_links".

Well I hope I got your question right.

**UPDATE 1**

default section is loaded everywhere. So IF I correctly understood u want only 1 single instance of block.

Try the following(local.xml):

```
<default>

    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cms_footer_links</name></action>

         <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.links.wrapper" translate="label" before="-">
            <label>Footer Links Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottomLinks</value></action>

            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links"/>
         </block>
</default>
```

OR

```
<default>

    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="cms_footer_links" />



         <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.links.wrapper" translate="label" before="-">
            <label>Footer Links Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottomLinks</value></action>
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_another_footer_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
            </block>
         </block>
   </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: yes, rigth. It works then. But it works in case I remove cms_footer_links. What if we don't remove cms_footer_links? Is it possible to update it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your remove-tag contains the wrong block name. It should be `<remove name="cms_footer_links" />` instead of `<remove name="footer_links" />`.